# Notify Events When logged in and logged out backbone js with coffeescript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm a little confused with backbone js.

I have multiple views that act differently based on session. ie. When I'm logged in all my views will allow me to like a comment and follow an issue but when i'm logged out, all the other views corresponding to the user activity should prompt a login form.

So, the confusion is about, how should I notify other views when I'm logged in so that they allow me to do the corresponding activities.

I'm currently able to achieve this but I need to refresh the page after I log in but then the purpose of backbone js is not fulfilled.

User model: user.js.coffee

```
class window.User extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/users'

  isSignedIn: ->
    Boolean(@get('remember_token'))

  login: (attributes, options) ->
    options.url = Root + '/sessions'
    @save(attributes, options)

  signup: (attributes, options) ->
    options.url = Root + '/users/create'
    @save(attributes, options)
```

Sign in view: signin_view.js.coffee

```
class window.UserView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll(this, 'onSignedIn', 'onSignedUp', 'onCommented')
    $(@el).show()

    if @model.isSignedIn()
      @showUserDetails()
    else
      Some code here
```

User details view: user_detail_view.js.coffee

```
class window.UserDetailsView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll(this, 'onValidUser')
    @model.on('change', @onValidUser)

   if (@model.get('email'))
     @onValidUser()
   else
     @model.fetch()

   onValidUser: ->   
     @render()

  render: ->
    $(@el).show()
      this.$(".name").text(currentUser.get('user')['first_name'] + ' ' + currentUser.get('user')['last_name'])
```

Now I want to notify my follow view that im logged in and I should not prompt for sign in form anymore, in fact all the views related to user activity

Follow view looks like this

```
class window.FollowView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    $(@el).show()
```

How do I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a bit of a structural problem. The "signed-in-edness" isn't really a property of a user, it is a property of the application as a whole: if they're not signed in then the application has no user, if they are signed in then the application does have a user.

So you should have an application object that has a user property. When the person signs in, set the user on the application object; when the person signs out, clear the user.

Once the above is in place, the solution naturally falls out: we're using Backbone so everything is based on triggering and listening for events and the events here are `signed-in` and `signed-out`. What triggers these events? The application object does. Who listens for these events? The views that care if someone is signed or not.

Suppose you have an application class like this:

```
class App
    constructor: (@user_name) ->
        _(@).extend(Backbone.Events);
    sign_out: ->
        @user_name = null
        @trigger('signed-out')
    sign_in: (user)->
        @user_name = user
        @trigger('signed-in')
    user: ->
        @user_name

window.app = new App
```

Then views that cared about the user could do things like this:

```
initialize: ->
    app.on('signed-in signed-out', @render)
```

and their `render` methods would be called when someone signed in or out; the `render` methods would, of course, check for the user and display the appropriate things.

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TfPf9/

Real code might want to have `remove` implementations to `app.off('signed-out signed-in')` to avoid dangling listeners.

And a couple other things while I'm here:

1. Using [`bindAll`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll) is rarely necessary with CoffeeScript. Instead of this:

   ```
   _.bindAll(this, 'onSignedIn', 'onSignedUp', 'onCommented')
   ```

   define the methods with [`=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow):

   ```
   onSignedIn: => #...
   onSignedUp: => #...
   ```
2. Newer versions of Backbone give you a jQuery/Zepto wrapped version of your `el` automatically so you can replace `$(@el).show()` with just `@$el.show()`.

Comment: Wow. This is the best explanation I could have ever had. Thank you so much for setting the base right. Thanks again :)